# GetX - The improper use of a GetX has been detected

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm trying to involve only one component of the page by GetX, and with that the application is popping an error.

[image]

Here are my components.

AuthController.

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class AuthController extends GetxController {
  RxBool isLoading = false.obs;
}
```

main.dart

```
void main() {
  Get.put(AuthController());

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

SignInComponent.dart

```
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    child: GetX<AuthController>(
                      builder: (_) {
                        return ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (_formaKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                              String email = emailController.text;
                              String password = passwordController.text;

                              print(email);
                              print(password);
                            } else {
                              print("Campos não válidos");
                            }
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            "Entrar",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: You don't have Rxtype variable inside GetX Builder, That's why it shown you a error

Answer (score 1):

Instead of
" RxBool isLoading = false.obs; " just use
"var isLoading = false.obs;"

When you went to use the "isLoading" value you can use the "isLoading.value"

In The below code no need to use the "GetX", Because GetX only can be used in Widget, When some value/data of the Widget is changed, Otherwise no need to use the GetX in Widget level.

```
SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                child: 
                    return ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_formaKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          String email = emailController.text;
                          String password = passwordController.text;

                          print(email);
                          print(password);
                        } else {
                          print("Campos não válidos");
                        }
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        "Entrar",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
               
              ),
```

Comment: i need to use a method developed in getx controller, so i need to wrap it